# SSRS Filter tablix data

Tags: reporting-services

I'm have the following rows displayed in the tablix data , which shows data for every week saturday for last  4 weeks . I don't want to modify the SQL that is used to display data here, rather use the SSRS chart to filter out the rows .

```
Date Count
3/5   2
10/5  4
17/5  7
24/5  9
31/5  10
```

As on today the date is 30/5 and thus it also displays 31/5 as returned from SQL . I need to filter out this weeks data , if it is not past satruday as such 31/5 should be filtered out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why don't you want to change to SQL? You are creating unnecessary traffic and SSRS has to handle bigger data sets which will not accelerate the process.

If i got you right, you have only saturdays in the data and you want to filter out saturdays which are in the future. So basically the condition is Date<=Today, or in SSRS Syntax Date<=Now().

Open Chart Properties, choose "Filters" from the Navigation on the left.
Add a new Filter.
For Expression, select your Date column.
As Operator select <=
Open the expression editor of the value field, enter =Now() and confirm.